# Linear Triangulation Strange Results

Tags: python, solver, triangulation, svd

Trying to implement linear triangulation in Python and getting strange results (e.g. why I get a sphere and why some coordinates are negative?). Not sure how to debug

I am trying to mimic a method described by [Harley & Zisserman](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lllL-LhTXpwJ:https://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/01/04/simple-triangulation-with-opencv-from-harley-zisserman-w-code/%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=no)[image]

**Data:**
Images from a car. Example:
[image]

**Approach:**
a) Find matching points in consecutive images. Example:
[image]

b) (Optional since I know my rotation and translation from the GPS) Essential matrix & pose recovery to get rotation matrix (R) and translation vector (t)

```
E, mask_2 = cv2.findEssentialMat(pts1, pts2, focal=focal_pixel, pp=(O_x, O_y), method=cv2.RANSAC, prob=0.999, threshold=3.0)
points, R_1, t_1, mask_2 = cv2.recoverPose(E, pts1, pts2)
```

c) Projection matrices for both images with no rotation and no translation for the first image

```
Pr_1 = np.hstack((np.dot(K, [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]), np.dot(K,[[0],[0],[0]])))
Pr_2 = np.hstack((np.dot(K, R_2), np.dot(K, t_2)))
```

d) Triangulation:

```
def linear_ls_triangulation(u1, P1, u2, P2):
    """Triangulation via Linear-LS method"""
    #u1 - homogenous image point (u,v,1)
    #P1 - camera 1 matrix
    #u2 - homogenous image point in 2nd camera
    #P2 - camera 2 matrix

    # build A matrix for homogeneous equation system Ax=0
    # assume X = (x,y,z,1) for Linear-LS method
    # which turns it into AX=B system, where A is 4x3, X is 3x1 & B is 4x1
    A = np.array([u1[0]*P1[2, 0] - P1[0, 0], u1[0]*P1[2, 1] - P1[0, 1],
                  u1[0]*P1[2, 2] - P1[0, 2], u1[1]*P1[2, 0] - P1[1, 0],
                  u1[1]*P1[2, 1] - P1[1, 1], u1[1]*P1[2, 2] - P1[1, 2],
                  u2[0]*P2[2, 0] - P2[0, 0], u2[0]*P2[2, 1] - P2[0, 1],
                  u2[0]*P2[2, 2] - P2[0, 2], u2[1]*P2[2, 0] - P2[1, 0],
                  u2[1]*P2[2, 1] - P2[1, 1],
                  u2[1]*P2[2, 2] - P2[1, 2]]).reshape(4, 3)

    B = np.array([-(u1[0]*P1[2, 3] - P1[0, 3]),
                  -(u1[1]*P1[2, 3] - P1[1, 3]),
                  -(u2[0]*P2[2, 3] - P2[0, 3]),
                  -(u2[1]*P2[2, 3] - P2[1, 3])]).reshape(4, 1)

    ret, X = cv2.solve(A, B, flags=cv2.DECOMP_SVD)
    return X.reshape(1, 3)
```

**Result:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Full code here** https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dK9w6xqDit5T8gx91qVyjUx2kgpPpROe

Comment: Please write a [mcve]. What is your expected output? Why are your result strange? Also do not post picture of text based data, copy paste instead. Do you intend to keep your notebook available once your question will be solved? If not the post will loose interest for other. Can you manage to share it in a long term way. That would be useful to the community and help you toward a answer.

Comment: From the double image which you posted it seems that different points on your images are not matched correctly. They should point to the same parts of the same objects on both sides, but most of them do not.

Comment: @Alex would that considerably affect the solver in practice?

Comment: Well, I don't know the details of the algorithm, but what I see is that "matching points" on the left and right images have the same relative positions. So, you tell your algorithm that all points have shifted by the same amount when you shifted the camera. It can happen only if all points have the same distance from the camera. So, what I see on the 3D graph are points which are lying on a sphere, i.e. have the same distance from the camera. That's why I guess the algorithm works ok, but the input from matching points is wrong.

Comment: @Alex it doesn't make sense to me that the points are on a sphere.. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Alex also it doesn't make sense to me that some points have negative coordinates

Comment: How can you measure a distance to an object? When you shift the camera the objects which are close to the camera move more, objects which are far away move less. If two objects move by the same amount it means that their distances from the camera are the same. You have selected a set of points on your left image. Then move a camera and make a second picture. Then you tell your algorithm that all the points which you selected just moved as a whole, not changing their relative positions. So algorithm concludes they all should be at the same distance from the camera.

Comment: - The essential matrix only exists for pinhole cameras. Your camera has nonlinear distortion. Looks like it might even be a fisheye?

Comment: That would be great if you edit your post to meet the Stack standard. Please update it to make a valuable post to the entire community, including you.